# RecyclerView не отображает данные, вылетает программа || Android Studio

Tags: java

```
            Класс адаптер:
            package com.example.personalaccounting;
            
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.os.Build;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            
            import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
            import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
            
            import java.util.List;
            
            public class CountingEntry_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CountingEntry_Adapter.ViewHolder>
            {
            
                private final LayoutInflater inflater;
                private final List<CountingEntry> Entries;
            
                public CountingEntry_Adapter(Context context, List<CountingEntry> Entries_)
                {
                    this.Entries = Entries_;
                    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                }
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public CountingEntry_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
                {
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                    return new ViewHolder(view);
                }
            
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public void onBindViewHolder(CountingEntry_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
                {
                    CountingEntry Entry = Entries.get(position);
                    holder.purchase.setText(Entry.GetPurchase());
                    holder.cost.setText(Entry.GetCost());
                    holder.dateofpurchase.setText(Entry.GetDateOfPurchase().toString());
                }
            
                @Override
                public int getItemCount()
                {
                    return Entries.size();
                }
            
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                {
                    final TextView purchase;
                    final TextView cost;
                    final TextView dateofpurchase;
                    ViewHolder(View view)
                    {
                        super(view);
                        purchase = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewlist_purchase);
                        cost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewlist_cost);
                        dateofpurchase = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewlist_dataofpurchase);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            MainActivity
           package com.example.personalaccounting;
        
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        
        
        import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
        import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
        
        
        import android.provider.MediaStore;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.time.LocalDate;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        {
        //Мобільне застосування «Особиста бухгалтерія»
            private ImageView ProfileImage;
            private MainActivity mainActivity;
            ArrayList<CountingEntry> countingEntries;
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mainActivity = this;
                countingEntries = new ArrayList<CountingEntry>();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                //
                ProfileImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Profile_Image);
                ProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent gallery = new Intent();
                        gallery.setType("image/*");
                        gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery,"Sellect Picture"), 1);
                    }
                });
                //
                Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                            countingEntries.add(new CountingEntry("Coca Cola",300,LocalDate.now()));
                            countingEntries.add(new CountingEntry("Pepsi",500,LocalDate.now()));
                            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerList);
                            CountingEntry_Adapter countingEntry_adapter = new CountingEntry_Adapter(mainActivity, countingEntries);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(countingEntry_adapter);
                    }
                });
            }
        
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
            {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1)
                {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    try
                    {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),imageUri);
                        ProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 2)
                {
                    
                    CountingEntry countingEntry;
                    countingEntry = (CountingEntry) data.getParcelableExtra("CountingEntry");
                    countingEntries.add(countingEntry);
        
                }
            }
        
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
            {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                return true;
            }
        
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
            {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.action_Add)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_AddNewCountingEntry.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,2);
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
   
   Текст ошибки
    I/sonalaccountin: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 10226(1085KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 91% free, 2343KB/26MB, paused 7.947ms total 32.117ms
    E/sonalaccountin: Invalid ID 0x0000012c.
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.personalaccounting, PID: 2057
        android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x12c
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6412)
            at com.example.personalaccounting.CountingEntry_Adapter.onBindViewHolder(CountingEntry_Adapter.java:40)
            at com.example.personalaccounting.CountingEntry_Adapter.onBindViewHolder(CountingEntry_Adapter.java:15)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
            at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
            at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2057 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Если вылетает - то в логах будет описание и место ошибки. Добавьте эти 2 детали в вопрос - с ними вам помочь будет легко, без них - очень сложно, долго, почти невозможно.

Comment: Зачем дважды написали код адаптера?

Comment: Не знаю какой вы код-конвенции придерживаетесь, но в широких кругах принято название параметров, проперти и методов писать с маленькой буквы. С заглавной буквы пишутся только названия классов. И не принято в названии классов использовать нижнее подчеркивание. Перенос открывающей скобки на следующую строку тоже моветон.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил описание ошибки и MainActivity

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что вы устанавливаете в качестве текста число. Система думает что это идентификатор ресурса и пытается его найти, не находит и выбрасывает исключение. Перед установкой числа в текствью, кастните его в строку(toString())

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.